# Insert blank row every 25% of the total rows adding the remainder to the last quarter

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to insert a blank row every 25% of the total rows adding the remainder to the last quarter.
Here is the code thus far:

```
Sub spilt()
Dim cnt As Long
Dim divisor As Long
cnt = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
#
#I'm assuming the logic goes here?
#
divisor = cnt / 4
MsgBox divisor & remainder

End Sub
```

I'm just not sure how it would split the rows by adding a blank row every 25% of the way, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub t()

 Dim last_row As Range

With ActiveSheet
    Set last_row = .Cells.Find(What:="*", after:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, searchorder:=xlByRows)
    cnt = last_row.Row
    div = cnt / 4 + 1

 Do
    i = i + Int(div)
    .Rows(i).EntireRow.Insert
Set last_row = .Cells.Find(What:="*", after:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, searchorder:=xlByRows)


 Loop Until i > last_row.Row

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
Sub spilt()
Dim cnt As Long
Dim divisor As Long
cnt = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
divisor = cnt / 4 + 1
Range("A" & (divisor)).EntireRow.Insert
Range("A" & (divisor + divisor)).EntireRow.Insert
Range("A" & (divisor + divisor + divisor)).EntireRow.Insert

MsgBox "Total rows " & cnt & "."
End Sub
```

Probably not the most elegant solution, but it works as I wanted it to.